# Highcharts Single Data Label in middle of Area

Tags: highcharts

This should be easy, I don't know why its not!

Trying to add a single label to for each of the series in the middle of the area.

So instead of a data label on each point, I just want one in the middle.

http://jsfiddle.net/CgAj2/

```
dataLabels: {
          enabled: true,
          align: 'center',
          verticalAlign: 'bottom',
          formatter: function() {return this.series.name; },

        }
```

Any anyone help with this? I am sure its possible by manually adding as positioning labels, but this seems like a work around.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not only for the entire series, you can have labels enabled for individual points also,

```
plotOptions:{
    arearspline:{
        datalabels: {
            enabled: false
        }
    }
}
```

in series data:

```
data: [37707.0, 37031.0, {
        y: 37037.0,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            formatter: function () {
                return this.series.name;
            }
        }
    },
    37748.0,
    39672.0,
    41747.0],
```

updated your fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/CgAj2/1/

hope this will help you

Comment: YES awesome you are a legend!!